# Project packer for Git

Tags: git, minify

I have a git server managed by GitLab, I was looking for a way to take the latest version of one of my projects from the git repository and automatically minify CSS, HTML and Javascript and get it ready for the production environment.

I think I could write a script with PHP using various minify libraries to loop inside each folder of the project and minify everything but I was wondering if there is some already tested way that can works with Git repositories.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Git. Why would it tie into the Git repo in any way, instead of just accessing the files in the working directory? You wouldn't actually want the results committed to the repository, they're *output* files, generated from files which are version controlled.

Comment: I'd like to take the source from Git, a kind of "Get source" button that downloads from git the "compiled" code. But if is not possible is ok even from the working directory. I was thinking about git to avoid to clone the entire repository in case I've not developed it but I just need the production code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I correctly understand your question , but you can create a shell script that pulls from the git repository and do the minification

May be a file update.sh that looks like. Assuming minify.php minifies your assets

```
#!/bin/sh
git pull origin master
php minify.php
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for something already tested, I can't belive I'm the only one with this need.